# Merge child nodes to other XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

Let say i have a XML document:

```xml
<Somethings>
  <everythings>
     <name>Mr.Johansson</name>
  </everythings>
  <nothings />
</Somethings>
```

and i have another XML document

```xml
<empty>
     <name>Mr.Doit</name>
     <age>94</age>
     <living>true</living>
</empty>
```

I want to copy all the child nodes from second xml to first xml´s `<nothings />` tag. So that i get

```xml
<Somethings>
  <everythings>
     <name>Mr.Johansson</name>
  </everythings>
  <nothings>
     <nothing>
         <name>Mr.Doit</name>
         <age>94</age>
         <living>true</living>
     </nothing>
  </nothings>
</Somethings>
```

I do get that i can copy all the child nodes with following:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
                version="2.0">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <nothing>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </nothing>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Edit: The question is to merge the child nodes into an element. Not about merging two sibling nodes into an element. 2nd the question is about getting all values and then merging into an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="path-to-external" select="'external.xml'"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="nothings">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document($path-to-external)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="empty">
    <nothing>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </nothing>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Replace `external.xml` with the path to the "other" document.

Comment: Thank you! That works, though it includes all the namespaces. That was the reason why i was doing it with {local-name}